# List By Category View

Tags: php, opencart

I have a view all category on the website I am working on (http://www.thetradinghouse.co.nz/view-all).  As you can see the products are not in order by category how could I change this as I also would like to do this with the admin product listings too.

V:  1.5.1.3

Comment: are you using SQL to get the products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of thing requires quite a bit of editing in the respective `model/catalog/product.php` files. This is how for the catalog side of things. The admin should require something similar. To start with, you're going to need to attach the category to the SQL like it does when the category filter is used

```
        if (!empty($data['filter_category_id'])) {
            $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c ON (p.product_id = p2c.product_id)";           
        }
```

Would then become just

```
            $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c ON (p.product_id = p2c.product_id)";
```

Since you want it to be available regardless of the filter_category_id

Then you need to add the category id as a sort option

```
        $sort_data = array(
            'pd.name',
            'p.model',
            'p.quantity',
            'p.price',
            'rating',
            'p.sort_order',
            'p.date_added'
        );
```

will need p2c.category_id adding to it

```
        $sort_data = array(
            'pd.name',
            'p2c.category_id',
            'p.model',
            'p.quantity',
            'p.price',
            'rating',
            'p.sort_order',
            'p.date_added'
        );
```

And also set the default sort if none is supplied, changing

```
$sql .= " ORDER BY p.sort_order";
```

To

```
$sql .= " ORDER BY p2c.category_id";
```

Finally you'll need to edit the controller for the said pages and find the default of the sort value, and change it to `p2c.category_id`

Comment: Could you explain what I am looking for interms of the sort value in the controller?

Comment: one of the values above in the $sort_data array, such as pd.name, for example, in the product.php controller, it has `$sort = 'p.date_available';`

Comment: The file that I am looking in is catalog/controller/product/product.php and I have just searched for $sort and this is not found.  Any Ideas

Comment: the product.php file is for the single product page view, so it doesn't have any sorting. Category, manufacturer, search all do as they display multiple products

Comment: Jay,  is this the location you are talking about?  Is this correct?    $this->data['sorts'][] = array(
    'text'  => $this->language->get('text_default'),
    'value' => 'p2c.category_id-ASC',
    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=p2c.category_id&order=ASC' . $url)
   );

Comment: That will set the sort dropdown yes, but there should be another value nearer the start of the page with $this->request->get['sort'] and it assigning a value to a sort variable a few lines below

Comment: Jay could you have a look at my documents https://gist.github.com/44408bb177b910cddc85  I think I have done it right but my view all category is still the same.

Comment: The edits look fine. Make sure you are using the correct controller for the view-all. It's not standard code, therefore you should have had a new file to view it with

Comment: Jay  The view-all is a category called view all so there is not a controller

Comment: ok, so you need to edit the `/catalog/controller/product/category.php` file you will see `$sort = 'p.sort_order';` near the top that needs editing

Comment: Jay That was the first document in the gist

Comment: so it was...that looks fine. Did you clear your cache folder?

Comment: Jay I have and that has made no change.